# Can I get the first X bytes from AWS S3 using Go SDK 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-go

I would like to get the first X Bytes from a very large CSV file. I basically just want to get the first two rows so I get the column names and an example of the data in each. However, I know that this isn't going to be possible so I would like to just download enough bytes to reasonably have enough data to be able to look at the first two rows. I am therefore trying to download the first 64kB.

I am trying to do this using the s3 manager ( https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/service/s3/s3manager/download.go )

I tried using something like :

```
downloader := s3manager.NewDownloaderWithClient(svc, func(d *s3manager.Downloader) {
    d.PartSize = 1024 * 64
    d.Concurrency = 1
})
```

`
This hangs though. I'd imagine I am just telling it to download the file with a small part size and it stops there and never returns anything.

Can anybody cleverer than me tell me how I can download just the first X bytes of an S3 file in go?
Thanks!

Comment: Go SDK is unfamiliar to me, but take a look at [`GetObjectInput`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#GetObjectInput) for the `Range` parameter, which is a string specifying the byte range you want to fetch in a `GetObject` request.  The first 1024 bytes would be specified as `bytes=0-1023` or just `0-1023` (docs are unclear).  What you're doing with the download manager is downloading the entire file, in 64K chunks, 1 at a time.